# Configuring Logback Appenders in Deployed Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, logback

I've got a Spring Boot application that is deployed in a Docker container. Since Spring Boot packages an executable fat jar, so far I can only figure out how to configure Logback by including the `logback.xml` inside that packaged jar's resources.

However, I don't believe this is best practice because it would require repackaging the entire jar and redeploying the jar just to configure the appender settings (for example, changing the log level or adding a new appender).

How can I package my Spring Boot application in such a way as to allow the Logback settings to be configured without needing to repackage/redeploy?

Edit: Here's my `logback.xml`

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>fullLogFile.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ROLL_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>rollingLogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%relative [%thread] %level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.my.app" level="trace" />
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ROLL_FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I package my Spring Boot application in such a way as to allow
> the Logback settings to be configured without needing to
> repackage/redeploy?

Just start your spring boot jar with the following parameter and put the logback.xml in the same folder with the jar. You must also remove the logback.xml from project resources.

```
-Dlogging.config=./logback.xml
```

It will then read it from there and proceed.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I tried this and it didn't work. I then tried with the full filepath (not a relative filepath) and it almost worked. The application created the log files, but it is not actually logging anything to those files, oddly enough. I'm using the same logback.xml that I was previously packaging with my jar, so I would think the same configuration would still work.

Comment: @AustinBrown consider adding logback.xml to the question to find out why it does not work. It should have worked

Comment: Sure, I've added my `logback.xml`. Just a note, but all of my classes are in derivatives of the package `org.my.app...`, so all of them should be getting traced, my log files remain empty. It does, oddly enough, look like my messages are getting logged to the standard out/console.

Comment: I figured out my secondary issue. I was using the `logback.configurationFile` property which, while being on the official documentation (http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty) doesn't unfortunately seem to work. I used the property you provided `logging.config` and it is now working properly, though I did have to use an absolute path for the property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker volume. Example docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  your-service:
    container_name: service-name
    image: your-service-image
    # environment variable path to your logback volume
    environment:
     - LOGGING_CONFIG=/data/logback_config/logback.xml
    # mount your logback file
    volumes:
      - ./logback.xml:/data/logback_config/logback.xml
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```